# LFR as synthesized data for dynamic community detection methods

Tags: dataset

In recent methods for community detection in dynamic networks, LFR benchmark is used as dynamic dataset generator, but I thought it is for static community based data generation. For example in paper [Overlapping Communities in Dynamic Networks: Their Detection and Mobile Applications](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~mythai/files/mobicom_CS.pdf), LFR is used. But I don't know how this dataset is generated.

[Here](http://pages.towson.edu/npnguyen/Databases/AFOCS.zip) is the code of this paper and ground truth included is only for one snapshot.

**Question: How is the dataset generated?**

Comment: Thank you very much ,but the tool you provided is non-overlapping network, how about the dynamic overlapping network?

Comment: @SamanthaChen As it is said, [here](http://mlg.ucd.ie/snam/) is for dynamic networks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the dataset is generated using dynamic network generator made available at [this address](http://mlg.ucd.ie/snam/) which is dynamic version of static LFR. It's an excellent dynamic networked data generator.